# error: no type named ‘_traits’ in ‘class date::year_month_day’?

Tags: c++, mysql, date, c++11, sqlpp11

I am using [Roland Bock's sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11) library for `mysql` queries and [Howard Hinnant's date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library for operation on date in my project.

And getting the following error in one of my update query.

```
/usr/local/include/sqlpp11/rhs_wrap.h: In instantiation of ‘struct sqlpp::rhs_wrap_t<date::year_month_day, false>’:
/usr/local/include/sqlpp11/assignment.h:63:12:   required from ‘struct sqlpp::assignment_t<sqlpp::column_t<changestreet::Goals, changestreet::Goals_::GoalEndDate>, date::year_month_day>’
sqlOperations/sqlppDbConnection.cpp:286:65:   required from ‘bool setEmergencyFundGoal(T1, T2, T2, T3, T3) [with T1 = int; T2 = const char*; T3 = double]’
main.cpp:705:113:   required from here
/usr/local/include/sqlpp11/rhs_wrap.h:119:43: error: no type named ‘_traits’ in ‘class date::year_month_day’
     using _traits = typename Expr::_traits;
```

And here is that update statement

```
auto efGoal = db_cs.run(update(g).set(g.goalAmount = emergencyFund,
                                                  g.goalEndDate = contributionEndDate, // Line number 286
                                                  g.goalContributionStartDate = currentDate(),
                                                  g.goalContributionEndDate = contributionEndDate,
                                                  g.goalInitialContribution = initialContribution,
                                                  g.goalMaximumAchievableAmount = emergencyFund,
                                                  g.goalCreatedOn = currentDateTime(),
                                                  g.goalUpdatedOn = currentDateTime()
                                                  ).where(g.goalName == goalName
                                                          and g.goalType == goalType
                                                          and g.usersUserId == userId)
                                    );
```

And here is the value that is being used in rhs

```
auto contributionEndDate = lastDateOfMonth(currentDate(), date::months{contributionTenure}) ;
```

Here is the definition of contribution `lastDateOfMonth()` function.

```
date::year_month_day lastDateOfMonth(date::year_month_day givenDate, date::months monthsNum) {
    date::year_month_day newDate = year_month_day{givenDate} + monthsNum;
    newDate = newDate.year()/newDate.month()/last;
    return newDate;
}
```

And the `currentDate()` function

```
date::year_month_day currentDate() {
    auto currentTime = system_clock::now();
    auto currentDate = floor<days>(currentTime);
    return currentDate;
}
```

Column name `goal_end_date` is of type `DATE` in mysql table structure.

Comment: What happens if you `g.goalEndDate = sqlpp::tvin(contributionEndDate),`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant `error: static assertion failed: tvin() used with invalid type (only string and primitive types allowed)`

Comment: Should I convert the `date::year_month_day` to `std::string` and then try to assign ?. Though I don't think it's a elegant way of doing.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.  I glanced at the sqlpp11 code and saw `tvin` associated with the error message and took a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change the mysql datatype from `DATE` to `DATETIME` and after that `system_clock::time_point` type variable assignment variables works like charm.

It will also work with mysql `DATE` dataype with variable assignment type `system_clock::day_point`.

P.S : I needed to modify the two given functin with return type of `syste_clock::time_point`.